# Deploy Imported Smart Contract in Test case

Tags: tokens, truffle-migration

I have a project that contains a Token Smart Contract,
it has been added to my project by means of:

```
npm install ../token_project
```

In my testcase I have:

```
var MyToken = artifacts.require("token_project/contracts/token/MyToken");
```

but when I

```
truffle migrate
```

the following error happens:

```
Error: Could not find artifacts for token_project/contracts/token/MyToken from any sources
```

The file is definitely in the folder, with the correct name and constructor.
I have tried referencing it directly by specifying ../node_modules but the problem persists.
Problem also occurs on other projects like openzeppelin_solidity - I can't use anything there in my tests for the same reason.

thanks

Comment: Aren't contracts usually in contracts/build, also you could try adding the file extension, sol

Comment: yes, but this import is for the json abi, which is available in after the build